# How can I apply KMEANS algorithm with determined cluster position which has specified from PSO algorith?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, particle-swarm

How can I apply KMEANS algorithm with determined cluster position which has specified from PSO algorithm ??

Answer (score 0):

Just *do* it.

K-means allows you to specify the initial centroids.

Answer (score 0):

Without any information on the nature of the data you're dealing with (number if dimensions, datatypes, outliers, overlap etc), it is impossible to give specific answers.

I don't know of any *genuine* k-means implementation where you can pass in  a list of centroids that  the algorithm uses to initialize the k-means centroids. Usually these are selected randomly. (Can't *you* write your own implementation of k-means that does this initialization? Simple take an open-source implementaion and add an argument)

However, In the python [sklearn implementation of kmeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html), there is a [kmeans++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B) implementation, where you can pass in the initial centers as an array.

```
init : {‘k-means++’, ‘random’ or an ndarray}

    Method for initialization, defaults to ‘k-means++’:

    ‘k-means++’ : selects initial cluster centers for k-mean clustering 
     in a smart way to speed up convergence. 
     ...
     If an ndarray is passed, it should be of shape 
     (n_clusters, n_features) and gives the initial centers.
```

Haven't used it, though.

*And I wrote this before I remembered/looked up **kmeans++:***

This is a poor-man's approach:

You can run kmeans with a `k`  parameter equal to the *length of the list/array* that the PSO algorithm (whatever it did) has given you.

Then kmeans will quickly find its own centroids. Do this several times, maybe with different distance-measures (Euclidean, manhattan, shortest, longest, avg...), and different seeds for your random-number generator. Each time, afterwards, compare the coordinates of the k-means centroids with the coordinates of the PSO centroids.

When there is a *near* 1:1 correspondence (depending on your requirements), you've found a match. then do something with your list of k-means classfication-results.